# Prevent Closing Of SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have a SweetAlert popup to confirm an action and I need to find a way to tweak it a bit to improve user experience.

First of all is that I have a button which fires the SweetAlert, this is for accepting applicants and sending an email to their email addresses. Now sending an email takes some time, like a few seconds.

What I did is I added a spinner on the button which fires the SweetAlert but the problem is, it's not noticeable to the users since firing the SweetAlert scrolls the whole page up and the button that fires it is waaaaay below.

So what I want is to add the spinner on the confirm button on the SweetAlert but the default is after clicking the confirm button, the SweetAlert closes.

Here is my code :

```
$("#accept_button").click(function(e){
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure you want to accept this applicant?',
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Accept Applicant'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        console.log($(this).data('url'));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            data: {key:$(this).data('key'),email:$(this).data('email')},
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#accept_button').attr("disabled", true);
                $("#accept_button").addClass("m-loader m-loader--light m-loader--left");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.ret) {
                    console.log('accepted');
                    Swal.fire(
                      'Success!',
                      'Applicant has been accepted.',
                      'success'
                    )
                    var delay = 1000; 
                    setTimeout(function(){ window.location = data.new_url; }, delay);
                } else {
                    Swal.fire(
                      'Failed!',
                      'Error occured.',
                      'warning'
                    )
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr) { 
                $('#accept_button').attr("disabled", false);
                $("#accept_button").removeClass("m-loader m-loader--light m-loader--left");
                toastr.options.timeOut = 5000;
                toastr.error('Error occured.', 'Error');
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
      }
    })
});
```

I hope you guys can help me out and the users of my web app. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "auto close timer" that way you will be able to show a message to the user and hold the attention of the user:

```
let timerInterval
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Auto close alert!',
  html: 'I will close in <strong></strong> milliseconds.',
  timer: 2000,
  willOpen: () => {
    Swal.showLoading()
    timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
      Swal.getHtmlContainer().querySelector('strong')
        .textContent = Swal.getTimerLeft()
    }, 100)
  },
  didClose: () => {
    clearInterval(timerInterval)
  }
}).then((result) => {
  if (
    /* Read more about handling dismissals below */
    result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.timer
  ) {
    console.log('I was closed by the timer')
  }
})
```

You can control the timer and even block the UI from doing anything else. Please look at the example "A message with auto close timer":
https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples